# Ejecutar dos funciones en setTimeout

Tags: setinterval

Muy buenas, tengo este código en el que pretendo que tras inactividad, se redirija a login.html

```
var nameTime;
function ini() {
    nameTime = setTimeout('location="login.html"',5000); 
 }
function parar() {
  clearTimeout(nameTime);
    nameTime = setTimeout('location="login.html"',5000); 
 }
```

Después

```
<body onload="ini()" onkeypress="parar()" onclick="parar()" onmousemove="parar()" >
```

Me gustaría poner algún tipo de aviso de que se ha redireccionado por inactividad, algo tipo toast o alert. Esto lo tengo ya, lo que no se es como hacer que el usuario vea algún tipo de mensaje cuando sea redireccionado

Comment: ¿que primero te redirija y despues un alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es que el `setTimeout` llamara a una función que mostrara el mensaje y, con otro `timeout` para dar al usuario tiempo a leerlo, redirija a la pantalla de login.

Algo así:

```js
var nameTime;
function ini() {
  nameTime = setTimeout(redirigir, 5000); 
}
function parar() {
  clearTimeout(nameTime);
  nameTime = setTimeout(redirigir, 5000); 
}
function redirigir(){
  document.getElementById('message').style.display='inline';
  setTimeout('location="login.html"',1500); 
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 10px;
}
#message{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: solid 1px #333333;
  padding: 15px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="ini()" onkeypress="parar()" onclick="parar()" onmousemove="parar()" >
<div id="message">
  Va a ser redirigido a la pantalla de login por inactividad
</div>
```